# I am having problems in running my Java programing Game

Tags: java

I have problem with my java game. i write all code no problem and programed JFrame run well but didn't start game. And I used Netbeans. Please find me find this problem.

this is my code

```
public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    private Dimension d;
    private final Font smallfont = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 14);

    private Image ii;
    private final Color dotcolor = new Color(192,191,0);
    private Color mazecolor;

    private boolean ingame = false;
    private boolean dying = false;

    private final int blocksize = 24;
    private final int nrofblocks = 15;
    private final int scrsize = nrofblocks * blocksize;
    private final int pacanimdelay = 2;
    private final int pacmananimcount = 4;
    private final int maxghosts = 12;
    private final int pacmanspeed = 6;

    private int pacanimcount = pacanimdelay;
    private int pacanimdir = 1;
    private int pacmananimpos = 0;
    private int nrofghosts = 6;
    private int pacsleft, score;
    private int[] dx, dy;
    private int[] ghostx, ghosty, ghostdx, ghostdy, ghostspeed;

    private Image ghost;
    private Image pacman1, pacman2up, pacman2left, pacman2right, pacman2down;
    private Image pacman3up, pacman3right, pacman3left, pacman3down;
    private Image pacman4up, pacman4right, pacman4left, pacman4down;

    private int pacmanx, pacmany, pacmandx, pacmandy;
    private int reqdx, reqdy, viewdx, viewdy;

    private final short leveldata[] = {
        19, 26, 26, 26, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 22,
        21, 0, 0, 0, 17, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 20,
        21, 0, 0, 0, 17, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 20,
        21, 0, 0, 0, 17, 16, 16, 24, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 20,
        17, 18, 18, 18, 16, 16, 20, 0, 17, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 20,
        17, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 20, 0, 17, 16, 16, 16, 16, 24, 20,
        25, 16, 16, 16, 24, 24, 28, 0, 25, 24, 24, 16, 20, 0, 21,
        1, 17, 16, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17, 20, 0, 21,
        1, 17, 16, 16, 18, 18, 22, 0, 19, 18, 18, 16, 20, 0, 21,
        1, 17, 16, 16, 16, 16, 20, 0, 17, 16, 16, 16, 20, 0, 21,
        1, 17, 16, 16, 16, 16, 20, 0, 17, 16, 16, 16, 20, 0, 21,
        1, 17, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 18, 16, 16, 16, 16, 20, 0, 21,
        1, 17, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 20, 0, 21,
        1, 25, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 16, 16, 16, 18, 20,
        9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 25, 24, 24, 24, 28
    };

    private final int validspeeds[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8};
    private final int maxspeed = 6;

    private int currentspeed = 3;
    private short[] screendata;
    private Timer timer;

    public Board(){
        loadImages();
        initVariables();

        addKeyListener(new TAdapter());

        setFocusable(true);

        setBackground(Color.black);
        setDoubleBuffered(true);
    }

    private void initVariables(){

        screendata = new short [nrofblocks * nrofblocks];
        mazecolor = new Color(5, 100, 5);
        d = new Dimension(400, 400);
        ghostx =  new int[maxghosts];
        ghostdx = new int [maxghosts];
        ghosty = new int[maxghosts];
        ghostdy = new int [maxghosts];
        ghostspeed = new int [maxghosts];
        dx = new int[4];
        dy = new int[4];

        timer = new Timer (40, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void addNotify(){
        super.addNotify();

        initGame();
    }

    private void doAnim(){

        pacanimcount--;

        if(pacanimcount <=0){
            pacanimcount = pacanimdelay;
            pacmananimpos = pacmananimpos + pacanimdir;

            if(pacmananimpos == (pacmananimcount - 1)|| pacmananimpos == 0){
                pacanimdir = -pacanimdir;
            }
        }
    }

    private void playGame (Graphics2D g2d){

        if (dying){
            death();
        } else{
            movePacman();
            drawPacman(g2d);
            moveGhosts(g2d);
            checkMaze();
        }
    }

    private void showIntroScreen(Graphics2D g2d){

        g2d.setColor(new Color(0, 32, 48));
        g2d.fillRect(50, scrsize /2 -30, scrsize - 100, 50);
        g2d.setColor(Color.white);
        g2d.drawRect(50, scrsize /2 - 30, scrsize -100, 50);

        String s = "Press s to start.";
        Font small = new Font ("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 14);
        FontMetrics metr = this.getFontMetrics(small);

        g2d.setColor(Color.white);
        g2d.setFont(small);
        g2d.drawString(s, (scrsize - metr.stringWidth(s)) / 2, scrsize / 2);
    }

    private void drawScore(Graphics2D g){

        int i;
        String s;

        g.setFont(smallfont);
        g.setColor(new Color(96,128,255));
        s= "Score:" + score;
        g.drawString(s, scrsize / 2 + 96, scrsize + 16);

        for (i =0; i<pacsleft; i++){
            g.drawImage(pacman3left, i * 28 + 8, scrsize + 1, this);
        }
    }

    private void checkMaze(){

        short i = 0;
        boolean finished = true;

        while (i <nrofblocks * nrofblocks && finished){

            if ((screendata[i] & 48) != 0){
                finished = false;
            }
            i++;
        }

        if (finished){

            score += 50;

            if(nrofghosts < maxghosts){
                nrofghosts++;
            }
            if(currentspeed <maxspeed){
                currentspeed++;
            }

            initLevel();
        }
    }

    private void death(){

        pacsleft--;

        if(pacsleft ==0){
            ingame = false;
        }
        continueLevel();
    }

    private void moveGhosts(Graphics2D g2d){

        short i;
        int pos;
        int count;

        for (i = 0; i < nrofghosts; i++){
            if (ghostx[i] % blocksize == 0 && ghosty[i] % blocksize ==0){
                pos = ghostx[i] / blocksize + nrofblocks * (int) (ghosty[i] / blocksize);

                count = 0;

                if ((screendata[pos] & 1) == 0  && ghostdx[i] != 1){
                    dx[count] =-1;
                    dy[count] = 0;
                    count++;
                }

                if ((screendata[pos] & 2) == 0 && ghostdy[i] != 1){
                    dx[count] = 0;
                    dy[count] = -1;
                    count++;
                }

                if ((screendata[pos] & 4) == 0 && ghostdx[i] != -1){
                    dx[count] = 1;
                    dy[count] = 0;
                    count++;
                }

                if ((screendata[pos] & 8) == 0 && ghostdy[i] != -1){
                    dx[count] = 0;
                    dy[count] = 1;
                    count++;
                }

                if(count == 0){

                    if ((screendata[pos] & 15) == 15){
                        ghostdx[i] = 0;
                        ghostdy[i] = 1;
                    }else {
                        ghostdx[i] = -ghostdx[i];
                        ghostdy[i] = -ghostdy[i];
                    }
                }else{

                    count = (int) (Math.random() * count);

                    if (count > 3){
                        count = 3;
                    }

                    ghostdx[i] = dx[count];
                    ghostdy[i] = dy[count];
                }
            }

            ghostx[i] = ghostx[i] + (ghostdx[i] * ghostspeed[i]);
            ghosty[i] = ghosty[i] + (ghostdy[i] * ghostspeed[i]);
            drawGhost(g2d, ghostx[i] +1, ghosty[i] + 1);

            if (pacmanx > (ghostx[i] - 12) && pacmanx < (ghostx[i] + 12)
                    && pacmany > (ghosty[i] - 12) && pacmany < (ghosty[i] + 12)
                    && ingame) {

                dying = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void drawGhost(Graphics2D g2d, int x, int y){

        g2d.drawImage(ghost, x, y, this);
    }

    private void movePacman(){

        int pos;
        short ch;

        if(reqdx == -pacmandx && reqdy == -pacmandy){
           pacmandx = reqdx;
           pacmandy = reqdy;
           viewdx = pacmandx;
           viewdy = pacmandy;
        }

        if (pacmanx % blocksize == 0 && pacmany % blocksize == 0){
            pos = pacmanx / blocksize + nrofblocks * (int) (pacmany / blocksize);
            ch = screendata[pos];

            if ((ch & 16) != 0){
                screendata[pos] = (short) (ch & 15);
                score++;
            }

            if (reqdx != 0 || reqdy != 0){
                if (!((reqdx == -1 && reqdy == 0 && (ch & 1) !=0)
                        || (reqdx == 1 && reqdy == 0 && (ch & 4) != 0)
                        || (reqdx == 0 && reqdy == -1 && (ch & 2) != 0)
                        || (reqdx == 0 && reqdy == 1 && (ch & 8) != 0))){
                    pacmandx = reqdx;
                    pacmandy = reqdy;
                    viewdx = pacmandx;
                    viewdy = pacmandy;
                }
            }

            // Check for standstill
            if ((pacmandx == -1 && pacmandy == 0 && (ch & 1 )!=0)
                    || (pacmandx == 1 && pacmandy == 0 && (ch & 4) != 0)
                    || (pacmandx == 0 && pacmandy == -1 && (ch & 2) != 0)
                    || (pacmandx == 0 && pacmandy == 1 && (ch & 8) != 0)){
                pacmandx = 0;
                pacmandy = 0;
            }
        }
        pacmanx = pacmanx + pacmanspeed * pacmandx;
        pacmany = pacmany + pacmanspeed * pacmandy;
    }

    private void drawPacman(Graphics2D g2d){

        if (viewdx == -1){
            drawPacmanLeft(g2d);
        }else if (viewdx == 1){
            drawPacmanRight(g2d);
        }else if (viewdy == -1){
            drawPacmanUp(g2d);
        }else {
            drawPacmanDown(g2d);
        }
    }

    private void drawPacmanUp(Graphics2D g2d){

        switch (pacmananimpos){
            case 1: 
                g2d.drawImage(pacman2up, pacmanx + 1, pacmany + 1, this);
                break;
            case 2:
                g2d.drawImage(pacman3up, pacmanx + 1, pacmany + 1, this);
                break;
            case 3:
                g2d.drawImage(pacman4up, pacmanx + 1, pacmany + 1, this);
                break;
            default:
                g2d.drawImage(pacman1, pacmanx + 1, pacmany + 1, this);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void drawPacmanDown(Graphics2D g2d){

        switch (pacmananimpos){
            case 1:
                g2d.drawImage(pacman2down, pacmanx + 1, pacmany + 1, this);
                break;
            case 2:
                g2d.drawImage(pacman3down, pacmanx + 1, pacmany + 1, this);
                break;
            case 3: 
                g2d.drawImage(pacman4down, pacmanx + 1, pacmany + 1, this);
                break;
            default:
            g2d.drawImage(pacman1, pacmanx + 1, pacmany + 1, this);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void drawPacmanRight(Graphics2D g2d){

        switch (pacmananimpos){
            case 1:
                g2d.drawImage(pacman2right, pacmanx + 1, pacmany + 1, this);
                break;
            case 2:
                g2d.drawImage(pacman3right, pacmanx + 1, pacmany + 1, this);
                break;
            case 3: 
                g2d.drawImage(pacman4right, pacmanx + 1, pacmany + 1, this);
                break;
            default:
            g2d.drawImage(pacman1, pacmanx + 1, pacmany + 1, this);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void drawPacmanLeft(Graphics2D g2d){

        switch (pacmananimpos){
            case 1:
                g2d.drawImage(pacman2left, pacmanx + 1, pacmany + 1, this);
                break;
            case 2:
                g2d.drawImage(pacman3left, pacmanx + 1, pacmany + 1, this);
                break;
            case 3: 
                g2d.drawImage(pacman4left, pacmanx + 1, pacmany + 1, this);
                break;
            default:
            g2d.drawImage(pacman1, pacmanx + 1, pacmany + 1, this);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void drawMaze(Graphics2D g2d){

        short i = 0;
        int x, y;

        for (y = 0; y< scrsize; y += blocksize){
            for (x = 0; x<scrsize; x += blocksize){

                g2d.setColor(mazecolor);
                g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));

                if ((screendata[i] & 1) != 0){
                    g2d.drawLine (x, y, x, y + blocksize - 1);
                }
                if ((screendata[i] & 2) != 0){
                    g2d.drawLine(x, y, x + blocksize -1, y);
                }
                if ((screendata[i] & 4) != 0){
                    g2d.drawLine(x + blocksize - 1, y, x + blocksize -1, y + blocksize - 1);
                }
                if ((screendata[i] & 8) != 0){
                    g2d.drawLine(x, y + blocksize - 1, x + blocksize -1, y + blocksize -1);
                }
                if ((screendata[i] & 16) != 0){
                    g2d.setColor(dotcolor);
                    g2d.fillRect(x +11, y + 11, 2, 2);
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    private void initGame(){

        pacsleft = 3;
        score = 0;
        initLevel();
        nrofghosts = 6;
        currentspeed = 3;
    }

    private void initLevel(){

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i<nrofblocks * nrofblocks; i++){
            screendata[i] = leveldata[i];
        }
        continueLevel();
    }

    private void continueLevel(){

        short i;
        int dx = 1;
        int random;

        for (i = 0; i <nrofghosts; i++){

            ghosty[i] = 4 * blocksize;
            ghostx[i] = 4 * blocksize;
            ghostdy[i] = 0;
            ghostdx[i] = dx;
            dx = -dx;
            random = (int) (Math.random() * (currentspeed + 1));

            if (random > currentspeed){
                random = currentspeed;
            }
            ghostspeed[i] = validspeeds[random];
        }

        pacmanx = 7 * blocksize;
        pacmany = 11 * blocksize;
        pacmandx = 0;
        pacmandy = 0;
        reqdx = 0;
        reqdy = 0;
        viewdx = 0;
        viewdy = 0;
        dying = false;
    }

    private void loadImages(){
        ghost = new ImageIcon("images/ghost.png").getImage();
        pacman1 = new ImageIcon("images/pacman.png").getImage();
        pacman2up = new ImageIcon("images/up1.png").getImage();
        pacman3up = new ImageIcon("images/up2.png").getImage();
        pacman4up = new ImageIcon("images/up3.png").getImage();
        pacman2down = new ImageIcon("images/down1.png").getImage();
        pacman3down = new ImageIcon("images/down2.png").getImage();
        pacman4down = new ImageIcon("images/down3.png").getImage();
        pacman2left = new ImageIcon("images/left1.png").getImage();
        pacman3left = new ImageIcon("images/left2.png").getImage();
        pacman4left = new ImageIcon("images/left3.png").getImage();
        pacman2right = new ImageIcon("images/right1.png").getImage();
        pacman3right = new ImageIcon("images/right2.png").getImage();
        pacman4right = new ImageIcon("images/right3.png").getImage();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        doDrawing(g);
    }

    private void doDrawing(Graphics g){

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

        g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, d.width, d.height);

        drawMaze(g2d);
        drawScore(g2d);
        doAnim();

        if (ingame){
            playGame(g2d);
        }else{
            showIntroScreen(g2d);
        }

        g2d.drawImage(ii, 5, 5, this);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        g2d.dispose();
    }

    class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

            int key = e.getKeyCode();

            if (ingame) {
                if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                    reqdx = -1;
                    reqdy = 0;
                } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                    reqdx = 1;
                    reqdy = 0;
                } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                    reqdx = 0;
                    reqdy = -1;
                } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                    reqdx = 0;
                    reqdy = 1;
                } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE && timer.isRunning()) {
                    ingame = false;
                } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_PAUSE) {
                    if (timer.isRunning()) {
                        timer.stop();
                    } else {
                        timer.start();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (key == 's' || key == 'S') {
                    ingame = true;
                    initGame();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

            int key = e.getKeyCode();

            if (key == Event.LEFT || key == Event.RIGHT
                    || key == Event.UP || key == Event.DOWN) {
                reqdx = 0;
                reqdy = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        repaint();
    }

    public class Pacman extends JFrame{

        public Pacman(){

            initUI();
        }

        private void initUI(){

            add(new Board());
            setTitle ("Pacman");
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setSize(380, 420);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run(){
                JFrame ex = new JFrame();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant part of your code in your question, not your entire code. Thanks.

Comment: So you wrote all of that before running the game and then discovered that it doesn't run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your game is started by `Pacman` class which create a jframe and add `Board` panel to it and etc. so instead of making a new jframe create a new `Pacman` object in main method and move your `Pacman` class outside of `Board` class .[this is complete code](http://pastebin.com/mmvjBBiN)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Pacman();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much.